# Convert kotlin to java to pass to Firestore

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to use this methods I used on a kotlin file in a java file, unfortuanetly I don't know how to do it in java. Could someone help me please?

Kotlin code to change to Java:

```
val progressDialog = indeterminateProgressDialog("Setting up your module")
            FirestoreUtil.getImportModules(ID, applicationContext) {
                val intent = Intent(this@AddModActivity, EditImportUserActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("moduleID", ID)
                intent.putExtra("moduleCode", code)
                intent.putExtra("moduleName", name)
                startActivity(intent)
                progressDialog.dismiss()
            }
```

It calls this method in firstore util ( does not need to change)

```
fun getImportModules(String: String = "", context : Context, onComplete: () -> Unit) {
    firestoreInstance.collection("assessment").whereEqualTo("module", String).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
                lateinit var realm: Realm
                Realm.init(context)
                val defaultConfig = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                        .schemaVersion(0)
                        .build()
                realm = Realm.getInstance(defaultConfig)
                val results = realm.where(Assessment::class.java).findAll()
                realm.executeTransaction {
                    results.deleteAllFromRealm()
                }
                if (documentSnapshot.isEmpty) {
                    onComplete()
                }
                else
                {
                    documentSnapshot!!.documents.forEach {
                        val s = Assessment(Double.parseDouble(it.get("achieved")!!.toString()),
                                it.get("date")!!.toString(), it.get("desc")!!.toString(), it.get("module")!!.toString(),
                                it.get("time")!!.toString(), Double.parseDouble(it.get("total")!!.toString()), it.get("type")!!.toString(),
                                it.get("weight")!!.toString())
                        //SAVE
                        val helper = RealmHelper(realm)
                        helper.save(s)
                    }
                    onComplete()
                }
            }
}
```

I know how to make the progress dialog and intent, what I don't know how to do is pass the intent through to the methods `onComplete()`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I know how to make the progress dialog and intent, what I don't know how to do is pass the intent through to the methods onComplete().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`() -> Unit` is converted to an instance of the `Function` interface in Kotlin.

That means you should be able to just create an instance of it:

```
FirestoreUtil.getImportModules(ID, getApplicationContext(), new Function<Unit>() {
    @Override
    public Unit invoke() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddModActivity.this, EditImportUserActivity.class)
        intent.putExtra("moduleID", ID)
        intent.putExtra("moduleCode", code)
        intent.putExtra("moduleName", name)
        startActivity(intent)
        progressDialog.dismiss()
        return Unit.INSTANCE; //notice this line; Kotlin treats the Unit class as void, but Java treats it as an actual class
});
```

If you're using Java 8 (targeting API 24 or higher and have it enabled), you can use a lambda, which makes it a little shorter:

```
FirestoreUtil.getImportModules(ID, getApplicationContext(), () -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddModActivity.this, EditImportUserActivity.class)
    intent.putExtra("moduleID", ID)
    intent.putExtra("moduleCode", code)
    intent.putExtra("moduleName", name)
    startActivity(intent)
    progressDialog.dismiss()
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```